# React Native Alert.alert refreshing app on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, alert

When I use

```
Alert.alert(
    'Incomplete',
    'Please make sure all required fields are filled before signing.'
);
```

in my React Native app, the Android app is unexpectedly refreshing.

Even though the alert is displayed to the user, the background of the alert momentarily switches from the current screen to the app's splash screen.

After dismissing the alert, instead of staying on the screen where the alert was triggered, the app navigates to the initial screen as if it were refreshed.

This only happens on Android

`"react-native": "0.73.1"`

Comment: Please share more of the source code here.

Comment: I edited the question @ko100v.d. It's just a normal use of Alert that's why I didn't add it in the first place